# Create Join Table for a belongs_to association in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `products` model and a `variations` model as a `belongs_to` association.  There are some variations that absolutely belong to a single product, but there are others that can belong to many products.  Can I create a join table on a `belongs_to` association like in a `has_and_blongs_to_many` association?

My Models Currently

**product.rb**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :variations, dependent: :destroy
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  has_and_belongs_to_many :subcategories

  include FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    name_changed?
  end
end
```

**variation.rb**

```
class Variation < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
    has_and_belongs_to_many :subcategories
    belongs_to :product

    include FriendlyId
    friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

    def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
        name_changed?
    end
end
```

Comment: if some `variations` can `have_many` products, why not using some kind many to many association? those `variations` who belong to one product will have only one record on the join table, and the other will have many records

Comment: @ZivGalili exactly. Studio Rooster has been doing this `association` questions in the past, maybe would help him reading a detailed guide about Active Record, Associations and Rails DB building

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio Maybe it would help if you and Ziv got a private room somewhere.

Comment: @ZivGalili Thank you.  My issue is that this is an active project and the client is now introducing variations that not only belong to a single product, but may belong to many; I don't have the luxury of restructuring the associations.

Comment: @StudioRooster when you do a "belong_to :product" association, the variations model expect to have a field named "product_id" which will point to the associated product, and since it can hold only one integer (one product id) the best option is to restructure. it makes no sense to use a "belong_to" as "has_many" association. just make it in steps so you won't lose data. first create the join table, then copy the info from your variations table (the variation.id and the associated product_id) and then start using it as a has_many association.

Comment: @ZivGalili That makes a lot of sense.  I'll talk with the client about restructuring.  Please create an answer I can mark as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Rails guides association basics - the belongs_to association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association):

> A belongs_to association sets up a one-to-one connection with another model, such that each instance of the declaring model "belongs to" one instance of the other model.

When you do the `belong_to :product` association on the `Variation` model, it expect to have a field named `product_id` which will point to the associated product.

use example:

```
variation = Variation.first
product = variation.product # this line will get the product which is associated to the variation by the product_id column.
```

Since it can hold only one integer (one product id) the best option is to restructure your code. It makes no sense to use a "belong_to" as "has_many" association.

You need to change the association to some king of many to many association.

To chose the best option for you, read and learn the differences in the [Rails guides - Association Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

*** Make sure you won't lose your data when changing the association:

Idea of doing that:

1. Create the join table
2. Copy the info from your variations table (the variation.id and the associated product_id)
3. Start using the new association

(You can probably copy the data in the migration file, just search how to do it)